# C# SqlParameter array how to conditionally set value to null using ternary operator

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following piece of code where I am trying to set a sql parameter to null if one of my object values is null and if not set it to a different variable value.

Ideally, I would just have `enumvalue` be null, but since this is an enum conversion for `EnumListValues`, nulls seem to be defaulted to 0.  So the ternary solution I came up with is to work around this.  I do not want my `enumvalue` variable to be 0 if `object1` does not exist.

```
public enum EnumListValues
{
    Disabled = 0,
    Enabled = 1
}

Enum.TryParse(object1?.Value, out EnumListValues.LightStatus enumvalue);
new SqlParameter("object1param", SqlDbType.Bit) {Value = object1 != null ? enumvalue : DBNull.Value } //enumvalue is 0 or 1
```

However I get the error:

> Error CS8370
> Feature 'target-typed conditional expression' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 9.0 or greater

Comment: did you try to update the project c# version?

Comment: Is that the recommended solution for my problem? I just want to know if that is the best way to solve my problem or if I should try a different approach.

Comment: You may try boxing here `{Value = object1 != null ? (object)enumvalue : (object)DBNull.Value }`

Comment: @Eldar Only one of them has to be cast to `object` and then the operator will know to implicitly cast the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest answer is to use a ternary with the return from TryParse to get what you want.  This would turn enumvalue into a LightStatus? which you can then feed into your SqlParameter.

```
var enumvalue = Enum.TryParse(object1?.Value, out EnumListValues.LightStatus tmp) 
    ? (object)tmp
    : DBNull.Value;
new SqlParameter("object1param", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = enumvalue; 
//enumvalue is a boxed 0, 1 or DBNull.Value
```

Comment: That seems to have worked, I guess I need to use the ternary and assign to the enumvalue variable in order to get the null value instead of using the tmp value which will be 0 by default it seems.